# How to make FileOutputStream.close() to throw exception myself?

Tags: java, exception, outputstream, fileoutputstream

In Java, FileOutputStream.close() may throw an IOException.
But I never see it happens.
How can I produce such an exception?
I need to produce this.
Thank you.

Comment: One question: Why? Are you attempting to test the innards of the .NET framework? Seems a bit irrelevant! You could always try and call close twice. That might do it

Comment: You can't. Don't test the platform, test your code.

Comment: The assumption is that the OP has a try/catch block or something similar and wants to test the behaviour of a failure condition. Also due to the tags, I believe this is a Java question (although I could be wrong)

Comment: @JonVD Not really an assumption, more of a logical inference from the text of the question. Your point remains obscure.

Answer (score 3):

If it's important enough, write a unit test to cover the scenario.

Consider using a mocking framework like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to simulate the behaviour you require without modifying your code. For example, you can get the `FileOutputStream` to throw a `IOException` by doing the following:

```
final FileOutputStream out = mock(FileOutputStream.class);
doThrow(new IOException()).when(out).close();
```

Once you have a mocked `FileOutputStream`, you can then pass it into the system under test, e.g.:

```
myComponent.writeTo(out);
```

The rest is up to you, for example, how should your system behave in this situation etc...

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to test what happens when an IOException occurs:

```
throw new IOException("Custom Message about the exception");
```

This will simulate the exception being thrown so you can see what happens in your application when such a thing occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Make a program that Writes a file to a USB, let it make a pause before closing the file, take out the USB and wait till the program will try to close the file.

Comment: You're assuming that the OP only needs to do this once, rather than in a (repeated) unit test. Even if that's the case, this answer seems ridiculously complicated compared to the others.

Comment: From "I never see it happens" I assumed OP wanted to see a real life situation